# Error when uploading iOS app after updating to Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, nib

I get these errors when uploading an iOS app in Xcode 7.0.1. No errors when using Xcode 7.0.

ERROR ITMS-90030: "Nib file 'MainWindow~ipad.nib' was not found. Please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename."

ERROR ITMS-90030: "Nib file 'MainWindow~iphone.nib' was not found. Please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename."

The app contains two xib files, but not any nib-files:
MainWindow.xib
MainWindow~ipad.xib

In Targets / General / Deployment Info: 
iPhone: Main Interface: MainWindow
iPad:   Main interface: MainWindow~ipad

In the plist-file:
Main nib file base name:  MainWindow
Main nib file base name (iPad) MainWindow~ipad

Is there an easy way to convert a xib-file to a nib-file?

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project? It's cmd+shift+K.

Comment: Yes, i've tried cleaning the project several times. The errors turn up every time. I've also updated Xcode to 7.1. The errors remain. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I've solved the problem. The xib files happened to be located in a sub-directory. Xcode 7.0 managed to find the files, but not 7.0.1. Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 4):

Check Info.plist of your project and find the entry NSMainNibFile~ipad, than remove this entry and try to Archive again. It should work :)

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me but why is it happening and how to get the build to automate properly without manually having to do this?

Comment: Isn't it possible to update your Xcode to 9? There has been a lot of improvements. Also it's a good practice to use the latest Xcode version.

Comment: Hi there I have XCode 9.

Comment: The questioner was using Xcode 7.0.1 But if it works now, I'd rather focus on other stuff now. The why it works is yet another question to be asked on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to delete both the entries `NSMainNibFile` and `NSMainNibFile~ipad`.

If you are using cordova, you can do that using a hook and the plist npm module

```
var xml = plist.parse(plistData.toString('utf8'));
delete xml['NSMainNibFile'];
delete xml['NSMainNibFile~ipad'];
return plist.build(xml);
```